# How to fine edit Visual Studio ASP.NET controls auto-complete settings?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, resharper

In Visual Studio Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Formatting > Tag Specific Options > ASP.NET Controls, it's possible to configure to a certain extent one by one each ASP.NET control.

When typing `<asp:Control` and then pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> Visual Studio completes it with `<asp:Control runat="server"></asp:Control>`, putting the cursor right between "server" and the closing angle bracket.

Is there a way through any Visual Studio settings, or through Resharper, to have *all ASP.NET controls* autocompleted with `<asp:Control ID="" runat="server" />`, with the cursor between the "" quotes of the ID tag?

Answer (score 1):

Try a Vs code snippet [here's how](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4c5cc9b(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Code Snippet Manager
You can see all the code snippets that are currently installed, plus their location on disk, by clicking Tools/Code Snippets Manager. Snippets are displayed by language.
You can add and remove snippet directories with the Add and Remove buttons in the Code Snippets Manager dialog. To add individual code snippets, use the Import button.

Comment: You could also use a ReSharper [Live Template](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Templates__Index.html)